# Elegant way to get duplicate statistics like missing values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': [101,101,np.nan,201,202],
                  'test_id':['A1','A1','A3',np.nan,'A4']})
```

This has a both of missing values and duplicate values in the dataframe

I would like to get the statistics of missing and duplicate values across columns.

It works fine for missing columns when I try the below

```
percent_missing = df.isna().sum() * 100 / len(df)
pd.DataFrame({'column_name': df.columns,
              'percent_missing': percent_missing})
```

[image]

but for duplicates, I would like to write like as above but it is clearly incorrect. It doesn't return me output column-wise (instead it provides me dataframe level)

I cannot use `subset` because I would like to check for duplicate values across all columns at once like we did above for `missing` using isna()

```
percent_duplicates = df.duplicated().sum() * 100 / len(df)
pd.DataFrame({'column_name': df.columns,
              'percent_duplicates': percent_duplicates})
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df_len = len(df)
percent_duplicates = [df[col].duplicated(keep=False).sum() * 100 / df_len
                      for col in df]
```

or with `apply`:

```
percent_duplicates = df.apply(lambda col:
                              col.duplicated(keep=False).sum() * 100 / df_len)
```

where we pass `keep=False` so that all the duplicates are marked as `True`,

to get

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"column_name": df.columns,
                  "percent_duplicates": percent_duplicates})

  column_name  percent_duplicates
0  subject_id                40.0
1     test_id                40.0
```